# Как сделать скриншот dialogfragment. NPE

Tags: java, android, screenshots

Публикую в вк результат игры. Если публиковать как сообщение , то результат можно редактировать в вк. Сразу приходит на ум вариант перевести результат в изображение. Не стал пока что искать библиотеки, которые могут введенное число сделать изображением да еще с красивым шрифтом. Пока хочу попробовать другое. В приложении ,когда проиграл появляется `DialogFragment` с результатом игры. Могу ли я сделать скрин этого диалога, а еще лучше определенной части этого диалога, так как в нем есть и то что не нужно для публикации.

**UPD**

```
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/wall"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

.

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
=
        View form = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.gameoverfragment, null);
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(form);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

        TextView currentTime = (TextView)form.findViewById(R.id.currentTime);


        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)form.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutResult);
        linearLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        linearLayout.buildDrawingCache();
        resultBitmap = linearLayout.getDrawingCache();
        return dialog;

    }
```

Далее вызвав `resultBitmap.getByteCount()` получаю `NPE`.  Попробовал добавить `resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(linearLayout.getWidth(),linearLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);` получаю ошибку, что  width and height must be > 0 . 
В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: С проблемой, что  размер linearLayout  показывал 0 разобрался. Я получал linearLayout.getWidth()  в момент когда он еще не создан.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете взять любую часть разметки и потом превратить ее в картинку так:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
linearLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
linearLayout.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap resultBitmap = linearLayout.getDrawingCache();
```

Здесь `LinearLayout` преобразовывается в картинку.

Comment: iramm, появляются ошибки, я их указал в дополнении к вопросу. LinearLayout как я понимаю, почему то не создается что ли..

Comment: Где то в этом же коде видел строку linearLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); после того как изображение получено.